# Phrase interpretable as expressing A, or as B, or as "A and B"

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Within the world of terms like *double entendre*, *multiple entendre*, and *polysemy*  is there a way of more specifically expressing the situation where

> there is a remark that can be understood to say A, or to be saying B, and it can be interpreted as saying both things.

"Simultaneous", "joint" or "conjunct" entendre come to mind but I have never heard such phrases in real use.

Comment: In the LitCrit biz we call this *ambiguity* -- sometimes *ambivalence* if the ambiguity is clearly marked as deliberately intended to communicate both readings simultaneously.

Comment: That is consistent with the use of *bivalence* for exclusive-or, A or B but not both.    Can *ambiguity* (unmodified, not *strategic ambiguity* or other variants) be used for something more specific than the existence of multiple interpretations?

Comment: '_Doublespeak_ is language that deliberately disguises, distorts, or reverses the meaning of words.' (Wikipedia) This is when ambiguities are intended, but intended to create a wrong impression. Wrt your comment, look up the clearly-written article at Wikipedia.

Comment: The edit was rolled back as the question is about: remarks that can be read as saying A, or can be read as saying B, or can be read as saying "A and B".  This is different from being readable as "A, or B", the disjunction.

Comment: I'm getting strong echoes of Tolkien here - "What a lot of things you do use 'Good morning!' for."

Comment: I can't think off-hand of a situation where context would not dictate interpretation. _Peter is a lady._ One assumes A is correct (true) (I've actually known a female with the name); B might be (lady as opposed to slut); and obviously the truth value of (A + B) follows that of A and B.

Comment: Well, in some situations the readings A-alone and B-alone are incorrect, but A+B does capture the meaning. @EdwinAshworth

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If A entails not-B, or B entails not-A, or both, (A +B) is ruled out.

Comment: In the situation that inspired this question, A-alone is subject to a criticism that amounts to saying "you ignored the collection of facts and circumstances surrounding possibility B!", and B-alone is subject to a similar "you ignored A!".  The combination (A+B) overcomes those objections, and is very plausible in context, but the remark is not written in such a way as to make it completely clear which of the three is meant.

Comment: 'Dextroboping is sanctioned at the Space Academy' Can mean (A) it is encouraged or (B) it is frowned upon and punishable BUT HARDLY BOTH. _Sanction_ is a Janus word. I think, however, that almost all words with different senses would not have senses that are mutually exclusive, and hence there is little need for a special term to _label a statement that can be understood to say A, or to be saying B, and also be interpreted as saying both things_. You can interpret according to normal rules any way you like. **What was intended** may have been A, B, or both.

Answer (score 1):

> Innuendo

This is a great term for implying multiple things, and letting context, inflection, social dynamics, etc. drive which *formula* of those multiple meanings the listener wishes to allow.

If the speakers are prepared for certain constructions, e.g. 'they are initiated', then the expressions can be called

> speaking in code

A technical word for this, when no context or intention exists to become sure the meaning:

> Indeterminate

Comment: Is there a word for the situation where veiling or indirection is not necessarily present?

Comment: @zyx sure, see my mod